# Export array to another file in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a Discord bot using discord.js, and I'm trying to import a huge array called "replies" from a file named "names.js".

names.js

```
export var replies = ['various stuff'];
```

bot.js

```
import {replies} from "names.js";
```

This just returns me the following error message

```
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/pi/discordbot/monsieur_bot/...'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I have tried enabling the "type: module" in the packages.json file, but this just breaks my code (the require discord.js bit).

Comment: Post your code, please. 
PS how do you require discord.js?

Comment: const {replies} = require(filepath)

Comment: I require discord.js using the require command, like this "const Discord = require("discord.js");"

Answer (score 0):

You should use the relative path, since your file is not a node_module.

```
import { replies } from "./names";
```

edit: If you cannot use modules on your node aplication, then you need to change your code for something like this:

names.js

```
exports.replies =  [foo, bar]
```

bot.js

```
const { replies } = require("./names.js");
```

Comment: Still throws me an error. "Cannot use import statement outside a module".

Comment: sorry, I had overwrited the .js when posting. Try again as show in the eddited answer

Comment: Yeah tried that too, still the same error sadly.

Comment: Also, if you want to use import, you must add "type": "module" to your package.json, otherwise it wont work

Comment: I edited the answer explaining how you can import a file without relying on modules, try that and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

> Use Relative Path

**names.js**

```
export var replies = ['various stuff'];
```

**bot.js**

```
import { replies } from './names.js';
```

**package.js**

```
  "type": "module"
```

Answer (score 0):

The paths in node js are relative to the file you are writing an example:

If you are writing in main.js and you want to import a module that is in name.js, assuming it is at the same height in main you would put `name from "./name.js".`

The keys are put if you are not doing an export default.

Another thing you have to use when you use exports is put in the package-json:

```
"type": "module",
```

> Blockquote